# The editing help page's title repeats the site name

Tags: bug, status-completed, editing-help

Minor thing I noticed: The [editing help page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) repeats the site name in the title. For example:

> Markdown Editing Help - Meta Stack Overflow - Meta Stack Overflow

This is the case for all SE sites. Especially noticeable when the site name itself has a dash in it:

> Markdown Editing Help - Gaming - Stack Exchange - Gaming - Stack Exchange

Comment: This needs fixing like _ASAP_! :)

Comment: Good catch! The ends of those lines are clearly missing "<– it has not changed in the last 10 microseconds."

Comment: Good catch.  I never notice these because I only see however many characters fit into the tab in Chrome for the page title.

Comment: No no no, you've got it all wrong! The first one is the Markdown source, the second one is the rendered version. It's a *demonstration!* Was that not clear?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nice find. Fixed in the next build.

I'll leave it as an exercise to the reader whether I removed the first or the second one.

Comment: I think you removed both and replaced them with an all new and improved version.

Comment: @ChrisF That's ridiculous. He removed the second half of the first and the first half of the second